# Windows SBS 2008 Backup fail

Tags: backup, windows-sbs-2008

I'm trying to backup my Windows SBS 2008 (only C:) with Windows Server Backup.
It fails a few minutes after it started:

```
Backup started at '08/12/2009 1:27:23 PM' failed as Volume Shadow copy operation failed for backup volumes with following error code '2155348022'. Please rerun backup once issue is resolved.
```

In the EventViewer i have lots of error :

```
VSS : 12289
SQLVDI : 1
MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE : 18210
MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE : 3041
SQLWRITER : 24583
```

All VSS ans SQL services are started. I have WSUS 3.0, Exchange 07.
I don't have any third party backup software running at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Antivirus running?  Some AV's lock access to files and cause problems like this.  Look in the event log for event 24583, which should provide some more information on what is failing.  If you share that information it may help narrow down the problem.

Update: Too much to put in the comments to Bastien's update.

Several references on the Internet to the error you posted, many pointing back to this post: (http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server/42606/SQL-Server-2005-SP2-Backup-Errors), where the solution was to re-register the VSS files:

net stop vss

From C:\windows\system32 register the following dlls and services:

regsvr32 ole32.dll
regsvr32 vss_ps.dll
Vssvc /Register
regsvr32 /i swprv.dll
regsvr32 /i eventcls.dll
regsvr32 es.dll
regsvr32 stdprov.dll
regsvr32 vssui.dll
regsvr32 msxml.dll
regsvr32 msxml3.dll
regsvr32 msxml4.dll
Regsvr32 EVENTCLS.DLL

net start vss

Also, on open regedit and search for EVENTCLS.DLL and ensure that the path to
eventcls.dll is always on C:\Windows\System32 (according to the path on
your server)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple partitions and if so, does the backup fail on those other non-system partitions?

Was SBS 2008 installed from the factory? In other words, is it an OEM installation? It's possible that the system partition is not marked as active. Have a look at this TechNet posting and see if you're willing to try the suggested fix: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winserverfiles/thread/d5daada2-b78b-4935-bd9e-80726c26c4a8/

**Disclaimer:** You will be using Diskpart as an admin. You can completely hose your system if you do not understand what you are doing. Read carefully. Act carefully. Live long and... well... you know. =)

Comment: Backup doesn't work on non-system partitions either.

SBS wasn't installed from the factory.
I don't find where to see if my C: is marked as active.
Diskpart doesn't show me that.

Comment: Go into disk management, right-click on the C: drive and see if you can select "Mark Partition As Active".

Comment: Actually, let me add a bit more information to the previous. Go into disk management and in the graphical listing of volumes in the top half of the MMC, look at the "Status" column and see which volumes includes the word "Active" in its status.

Comment: None, all are "Healthy", and my C: is "Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump)"

Comment: That could potentially be part of the problem, but I also wonder why C: is not also marked as "System" and "Primary Partition". Strange. You'll have to weigh the risks of marking your system volume as active. You might want to take the server offline and do a complete image of it with a tool like Ghost before marking it as active using diskpart.

Comment: If the backup don't work on a non-system and active partition, I don't think it will solve my issue, no ?

Comment: That thought occurred to me, but it's certainly not normal (in my experience, anyway) for a system partition to not be marked as active. I suppose that would be attempting to correct a possibly non-correlated problem, however.

Comment: There originally was a software RAID 1 with it, but it was horrible, so we killed it, there is a 2GB partition 'System', and a 78MB EISA Configuration.

Comment: That sounds all messed up to me. =|

Comment: I know, but I can't risk anything on it, exchange is our life and we have no backup...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few weeks back.

You need to check its not your Antivirus, so disable it for a few minutes and then try to run a backup. If this doesn't solve the issue, then try going into 'Services' and stop the 'SQL Server VSS Writer' - Now try to run a backup!